# Why is my datastax cluster down often?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a datastax center and the version of it is 4.8.7. 
The datastax cluster has 6 nodes (1 node for solr datacenter and 5 nodes for analytics datacenter), and every node is configured with 32 cores and 64G memory.

The spark application runs on analytics datacenter, the error log of this is

> ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690
>   SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 - Error writing stream to file
>   /var/lib/spark/worker/worker-0/app-20160923163007-0136/3/stderr ERROR
>   [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0
>   ExternalLogger.java:96 - java.io.IOException: Stream closed ERROR
>   [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0
>   ExternalLogger.java:96 -  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
>   ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,690 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,691 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1652)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,691 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] WARN 
>   [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,691 
>   Slf4jLogger.scala:71 - Tried to associate with unreachable remote
>   address [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:53714]. Address is now gated
>   for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead
>   letters. Reason: Connection refused: /localhost:53714 INFO 
>   [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,691
>   Logging.scala:59 - akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:53714 got
>   disassociated, removing it. INFO  [SparkWorker-0 logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,693 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:88 - Launch command:
>   "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/bin/java" "-cp"
>   "/etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/dse-core-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hadoop-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hive-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-search-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-spark-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-sqoop-4.8.7.jar:/etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/breeze_2.10-0.11.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/breeze-macros_2.10-0.11.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/chill-java-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/commons-net-2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/config-1.2.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-core-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jansi-1.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/javolution-5.5.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jline-2.10.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/joda-time-2.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jodd-core-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jpam-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/json-20090211.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/paranamer-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-column-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-common-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-encoding-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-format-2.2.0-rc1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-generator-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/parquet-jackson-1.6.0rc3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/pmml-agent-1.1.15.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/pmml-model-1.1.15.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/pmml-schema-1.1.15.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0-spark.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/py4j-0.8.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/pyrolite-4.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/RoaringBitmap-0.4.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/scalap-2.10.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/snappy-0.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-bagel_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.4.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-catalyst_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-graphx_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-hive_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-launcher_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-mllib_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-network-common_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-repl_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-sql_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spire_2.10-0.7.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spire-macros_2.10-0.7.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/ST4-4.0.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/stream-2.7.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/tachyon-0.6.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/tachyon-client-0.6.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/unused-1.0.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-0.13.1-cassandra-connector-0.2.14.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-0.13-metastore-cassandra-connector-0.2.14.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-beeline-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-cli-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-common-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-exec-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-jdbc-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-metastore-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-serde-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-service-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.20-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.20S-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.23-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-common-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/hive-shims-common-secure-0.13.1a.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-ber-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-i18n-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-client-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-core-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-standalone-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-model-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-net-mina-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-util-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-pool-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guava-16.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-multibindings-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/HdrHistogram-1.2.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/janino-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/java-uuid-generator-3.1.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/journalio-1.4.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/kmip-1.7.1e.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/log4j-1.2.13.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/mina-core-2.0.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/stringtemplate-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/etc/dse/:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/:/etc/dse/hadoop/:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/ant-1.6.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/ftplet-api-1.0.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/ftpserver-core-1.0.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/ftpserver-deprecated-1.0.0-M2.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-examples-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-test-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hadoop-tools-1.0.4.18.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/mina-core-2.0.0-M5.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/netty-3.9.8.Final.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/../driver/lib/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/../driver/lib/cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/../driver/lib/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/../driver/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/etc/dse/cassandra/:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/tools/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-clientutil-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-thrift-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/fastutil-6.5.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/joda-time-1.6.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.12.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/etc/dse/hadoop/"
>   "-Xms2048M" "-Xmx2048M" "-Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=64264"
>   "-Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader"
>   "-Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra"
>   "-Ddse.client.configuration.impl=com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.HadoopBasedClientConfiguration"
>   "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/etc/dse/spark/logback-spark-executor.xml" "org.apache.spark.DseSecureRunner"
>   "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend"
>   "--driver-url"
>   "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:57972/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler"
>   "--executor-id" "4" "--hostname" "localhost" "--cores" "11" "--app-id"
>   "app-20160923163206-0137" "--worker-url"
>   "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:53730/user/Worker" ERROR
>   [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0
>   ExternalLogger.java:96 - Error writing stream to file
>   /var/lib/spark/worker/worker-0/app-20160923163007-0136/3/stdout ERROR
>   [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0
>   ExternalLogger.java:96 - java.io.IOException: Stream closed ERROR
>   [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0
>   ExternalLogger.java:96 -  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error logger] 2016-09-23
>   16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
>   ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,696 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,697 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,697 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1652)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5] ERROR [SparkWorker-0 error
>   logger] 2016-09-23 16:40:10,697 SparkWorker-0 ExternalLogger.java:96 -
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.5.jar:1.4.2.5]

Besides, a large file named with java_1464320280.hprof will be generated automatically. 
The size of this file is so large that it will run out of system disk space, which will let cassandra node down finally.

Comment: *Reason: Connection refused: /localhost:53714*. Are you sure all ports are properly open for all workers to connect to master and vice versa?

Comment: Your port refers to what?A few months ago，datastax system operating normally,but the past week,server downtime often。I have configured export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=3600"，but it does not work for me.How can I slove the error log I have already mentioned.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did anything change? Spark Master IP? Network permissions? Firewall?

Comment: I changed all these but no result so far. any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: the hprof file is a heap dump. I would venture to guess that you're running out of heap memory. Your nodes have 64G ram, what's your Xmx setting?